# Blender is not running on Nvidia gtx 1050TI

Tags: installation

**Problem**
I tried to install Blender software on my computer. I tried installing it via the .msi file downloaded from the blender site.

Installation was a success, but I was unable to run the app, neither as a user or administrator.

Each time I was receiving Exception_Acces_Violation and the app was not running.

**What I have tried so far**
After installation, I tried to use OpenGL to run it, but there was no success. I have also tried to run via command line and even in debug mode - I was still receiving Exception as stated over.

After those problems, I've decided to download it as a zip, unzip it, and create a shortcut to it. Also - I have changed my computer to use Intel GPU rather than Nvidia GPU for Blender and somehow I was able to run Blender finally. The only thing I was mad about was performance - it was more than bad.

What I hope I would like to run it on Nvidia with better performance. For now, I have no idea what to do.

I am trying to run in on a laptop, specs below:

- **Processor** Processor Intel Core i7 7th Gen 7700HQ Base Clock Speed 2.8 GHz Cache 6MB
- **Memory** RAM 16GB
- **Graphics** Graphics Processor Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Dedicated Graphic Memory Type DDR5
- **OS** Microsoft 10 Home Edition OEM

Comment: Update the drivers for the gpu

Comment: I have already upgraded all drives for my computer. Still same :/

Comment: Have you tried 2.83 LTS?  I can't believe a 1050Ti wouldn't work, but apparently there are some users experiencing similar in the google resullts.  Worst case use CPU rendering.

Comment: I did tried with same error! Also - worst thing, It runs on CPU rendering. Performance is worse than bad.... I am really mad because of this and it makes me furious such a thing is happening :/

Comment: Have you tried `blender --debug-gpu-force-workarounds`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could be helpfull, but try to unistall blender, after this try to reinstall it again from Steam

Comment: Done. Same exception occured -.-